# MySql error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

in my RIM I got the 1215 MySql error.

I know the meaning of the error, that my constraints are wrong. But I can't seem to fix it.

the error is at line 33, the creation of `table Poker_event`

```
create table Poker_event
   (date_time       datetime    not null,
    min_players     int         not null,
    max_players     int         not null,
    house_number    int         not null, 
    postal_code     varchar(6)  not null,
primary key(date_time),
foreign key(house_number, postal_code)   references Location(house_number, postal_code) on delete set null on update cascade);
```

my code is:

```
create database FullHouseGr1;
use FullHouseGr1;
create table Player
   (player_id       int             not null,
    first_name      varchar(20)     not null,
    surname         varchar(20)     not null,
    addres          varchar(40)     not null,
    postal_code     varchar(6)      not null,
    place           varchar(40)     not null,
    phone_number    varchar(20)     not null,
    email_addres    varchar(255)    not null,
    points          int             not null,
primary key(player_id));

create table Location
   (house_number    int       not null,
    postal_code     varchar(6)  not null,
    capacity        int       not null,
    place           varchar(40) not null,
    street          varchar(40) not null,
primary key(house_number, postal_code));

create table Poker_event
   (date_time       datetime    not null,
    min_players     int         not null,
    max_players     int         not null,
    house_number    int         not null, 
    postal_code     varchar(6)  not null,
primary key(date_time),
foreign key(house_number, postal_code)   references Location(house_number, postal_code) on delete cascade on update cascade);

create table Tournament
   (date_time   datetime    not null,
    prize       int         not null,
primary key(date_time),
foreign key(date_time)  references Poker_event(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade);

create table Tournament_round
   (round_nr    int       not null,
    date_time   datetime    not null,
primary key(date_time, round_nr),
foreign key(date_time)  references Tournament(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade);

create table Tournament_table
   (winner      int         not null,
    date_time   datetime    not null,
    round_nr    int         not null,
primary key(winner, date_time, round_nr),
foreign key(date_time)  references Tournament(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade,
foreign key(round_nr)   references Tournament(round_nr) on delete no action on update cascade);

create table Professional
   (p_name    varchar(40) not null,
primary key(name));

create table Masterclass
   (date_time       datetime    not null,
    min_rating      int       not null,
    name            varchar(40) not null,
primary key(date_time),
foreign key(p_name)       references Professional(p_name) on delete no action on update cascade,
foreign key(date_time)  references Poker_event(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade);

create table Poker_event_player
   (date_time   datetime    not null,
    has_payed   boolean     not null,
    player_id   int         not null,
primary key(date_time,  player_id),
foreign key(date_time)  references Poker_event(date_time) on delete no action on update cascade,
foreign key(player_id)  references Player on delete no action on update cascade);

create table    Player_tournament_table
   (winner      int         not null,
    date_time   datetime    not null,
    round_nr    int         not null,
    player_id   int         not null,
primary key(winner, date_time, round_nr, player_id),
foreign key(winner)     references  Tournament_table on delete no action on update cascade,
foreign key(round_nr)   references  Tournament_round on delete no action on update cascade,
foreign key(date_time)  references  Tournament on delete no action on update cascade,
foreign key(player_id)  references  Player on delete no action on update cascade);
```

Comment: Where is line 33? Also, what is the **exact** error posted by MySQL?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi The exact error message is `1215 - cannot add foreign key`. @blipman I posted a wrong answer you don't need the referencing columns to be indexed (but you should do it tho!), @mopo922 is right.

Comment: @DanFromGermany that error is partially incomplete. MySQL gives a description that resulted to the cause of the error.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I may not from my teachers. because... this would result in unused data. `house_number, postal_code` is unique in The Netherlands

Comment: Since this question is old and you had already accepted an answer (which you seem to have un-accepted now?), you might want to ask a new question for your new issue. It's hard to sift through what has changed.

Comment: cannot ask a new question in 90 minutes of posting an old one, I'm sorry :/

Comment: Hmm, well those look like different issues. For example, `Tournament(round_nr)` should be `Tournament_round(round_nr)` right?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't make a difference for the error. Does it make a difference if I would use my database? I got to say that I really appreceate all your help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: forget it, I'll just wait the resting 30 minutes and do it in a "proper" post of that error. thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're saying `ON DELETE SET NULL` but both of the fields in question are not nullable. Try `ON DELETE CASCADE` instead.

You can also check to make sure both tables are using the InnoDB engine.

Comment: And what do I need to use to do delete the row on ``ON DELETE``? I'm batteling verry hard with ``ON DELETE`` and ``ON UPDATE``

Comment: @blipman17 can you just replace `on delete set null on update cascade` with `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`?

Comment: That would delete Poker_event's

Comment: @blipman17, how bout going a completely different structure, using real ID's.. what if someone changes his/her postal code?

Comment: @DanFromGermany, I use ``player_id`` for people and use ``house_number, postal_code``for places, since that's unique in The Netherlands